# jQuery change URL with Form answers

Tags: jquery

I have a question regarding changing the URL that has some form information but might cause duplications. It's kind of hard to explain in one sentence. So I have a form for searching and trying to do pagination using a drop down. The URL would be something like this:

http://www.site.com/page/?name=Amanda&state=WA&approved=-2&form_date=&submit=Submit

...and the code below adds the page call just fine (for example)

http://www.site.com/page/?name=Amanda&state=WA&approved=-2&form_date=&submit=Submit&page=2

However if they change the page again, it's gonna duplicate the page call so it'll be

http://www.site.com/page/?name=Amanda&state=WA&approved=-2&form_date=&submit=Submit&page=2&page=2

I know how to fix it via PHP, but I'd like to keep it in jQuery if possible. Below is my jQuery call. Would I have to do an indexOf call? Is that the only way? I thought there was another way so I thought I'd just ask.

```
$('#page').change(function(){
    var pathName = window.location.search;
    var page_change = $('#page option:selected').val();
    if(pathName == ""){
        window.location.replace("?page="+page_change);
    } else {
        window.location.replace(pathName+"&page="+page_change);
    }
```

});

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

```
$('#page').change(function(){
    var pathName = window.location.search;
    var page_change = $('#page option:selected').val();
    if(pathName == ""){
        window.location.replace("?page="+page_change);
    } else {
        path_arr = pathName.substr(1).split('&');
        new_path = new Array();
        for(p in path_arr) {
            if (path_arr[p].indexOf('page') == -1) {
                new_path.push(path_arr[p]);
            }
        }
        window.location.replace('?' + new_path.join() + '&page=' + page_change);
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked great! I just had to tweak the code a bit and it worked beautifully! Thank you! :)